# java code to download an image from server to client

Tags: java, image, download

I am a new to java. I dont know much about it. I am just learning java.
I am developing a web application. In which i have an option download image . If user clicks he should be able to download image from server to client side say at location c://.

I have implemented this code ::

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;


import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;




public class DownloadingImages{
    public DownloadingImages() {}

public void download(String name) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{

Image image = null;
try {
    //URL url = new URL("file:///E:/myproject/build/web/images/Webcam.jpg");

 String  spath="http://localhost:5051/marketpoint/images/";

 String cpath="C:\\";


 spath = spath + name ;
 cpath = cpath + name ;
 System.out.println("FULL path::: "+spath);



 URL url = new URL(spath);




 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
int n = 0;
while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf)))
{
   out.write(buf, 0, n);
}
out.close();
in.close();
byte[] response = out.toByteArray();
 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(cpath);
    fos.write(response);
    fos.close();  
} catch (IOException e) {


}
}
}


Here
name = name of image thta client wants to download.
```

Here problem is that image gets downloaded to server's side. At c:// . can anybody please tell where  am i going wrong.

For this i am using net beans as my editor , Apache tomcat as  server.  Both client and Server gets connected through port no 5051. And image that clients want to download from server is simple jpg image.  will anybody help me to get out of this problems.

Comment: you mention you have problems but neglect to say what they are specifically. I also find it hard to believe that someone would vote this question up.

Comment: If this is a learning situation, you should tag your question as homework.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience i have updated my problem. and problem is that it gets downloaded to servers side at c:// and not to clients side

Answer (score 0):

If the file is getting downloaded to C:\, then that's what your `cpath` variable equals when you open your `FileOutputStream`. This would imply that your `name` variable is being passed in as an empty string. Try putting in some logging statements (or even better, using the netbeans debugger!) to see what values your variables are holding as your code executes.

EDIT: I think I understand the problem now. You're running this as a servlet or something similar. That means that your code is executing on the server, rather than the client. If you want to download the file to a specific path on the client, you're going to have to use an `Applet` or something similar that runs on the client side. Alternatively, you can return the file in the HTTP response and the user's browser will ask them where to save the file. Although, at that point, the user could just navigate to the jpg in a browser themselves.

You might want to explain your use case in more detail if this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I debugged my program name is name of image and it is correct. i just want that it should get downloaded to client side and not server side. for that what should i do ?

Comment: @user1191852 See my updated response. I think I understand your question now!

Comment: sir can i get code for such program. I have my deadlines close

Comment: sir its like simple download option which you may while browsing websites and where you just click on download link and respected file or image gets downloaded. i want similar program. Please anybody can help me ?

Comment: Like I said, you'll have to send back the raw data in the HTTP Response. If you post the full code of your servlet (I assume?) we can help more. However, noone here is going to write an application for your from scratch. You have to try it yourself and we can help you along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this running code.It will help you.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URL;

public class SaveImageFromUrl {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        String imageUrl = "http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_GHaEnqqbRsE/SVsxi-gdQ2I/AAAAAAAAAAU/NS6MEejoHtE/s320/Gppfront.jpg";


        String destinationFile = "D://gpp.jpg";

        saveImage(imageUrl, destinationFile);
    }

    public static void saveImage(String imageUrl, String destinationFile) throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

        byte[] b = new byte[2048];
        int length;

        while ((length = is.read(b)) != -1) {
            os.write(b, 0, length);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this working code first:

```
package com.ashugupt.github.stackover;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class URLTest {

  private static void sendGet() throws Exception {

    String url = "http://www.uni-koblenz-landau.de/images/starts-c-ko.jpg";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/Users/ravikiran/Desktop/abc.jpg");
    try {
      byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
      int length;

      while ((length = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, length);
      }
    } finally {
      in.close();
      out.close();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    sendGet();
  }
}
```